# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies empty for published app

Tags: c#, winforms, publish

Building an app such as Winforms and using the

```cs
var myAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies ()
```

will return all assemblies of the project. However, using the Publish instead of build `myAssemblies` is empty. I think it is because the *SingleFile* is *true*, which is exactly what I want.

Is there any way to load all assemblies even in Publish with SingleFile option?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/70438